# Can't display my turtle object in my Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm very new to Python. I wanted to display a turtle object on top of a canvas in Tkinter. I'm not sure why the object is not displaying.

I used the `RawTurtle()` in order to use the Tkinter canvas as screen.

```
root =tk.Tk()

outercanvas = Canvas(root, width=900, height=800, bg='#00ffff')
outercanvas.pack(expand=Y,fill=BOTH)

innercanvas = Canvas(outercanvas, width=680, height=700)
outercanvas.create_window(100, 40, anchor=NW, window=innercanvas)


bg = tk.PhotoImage(file="level2.png")
innercanvas.create_image(-5, 0, image = bg, anchor=NW)



bob = turtle.RawTurtle(innercanvas)
```

I expect the turtle to appear on top of the canvas, so that I can manipulate it later.
[image: I want the turtle to appear in the inner canvas]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image and the turtle appear to be in conflict.  Try it this way instead:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

root = tk.Tk()

outercanvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=900, height=800, bg='#00ffff')
outercanvas.pack(expand=tk.Y, fill=tk.BOTH)

innercanvas = tk.Canvas(outercanvas, width=680, height=700)
outercanvas.create_window(100, 40, anchor=tk.NW, window=innercanvas)

screen = TurtleScreen(innercanvas)
screen.bgpic("level2.gif")

bob = RawTurtle(screen)

bob.circle(100)

screen.mainloop()
```

Note that I had to make and use "level2.gif" for this to work but you may have a newer underlying tkinter, and turtle, that accepts PNG files.